# WINAPI SetLastError versus C++ Keword Throw

Tags: c++, winapi, exception, custom-errors

What is the difference between the WINAPI `SetLastError()` and the C++ keyword `throw`?  For example, are `SetLastError(5);` and `throw 5;` the same?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SetLastError sets a simple global variable, it does nothing to the flow of the program.

throw would stop the flow of the running program, unwind the stack until it is caught somewhere with a try - catch clause. The program flow would then continue from the end of the catch.

I suggest reading [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_handling) article, which explains the concept of exceptions. And read up on C++ exceptions.

- Also, don't throw 5, throw an non-built in object, preferably inherited by std::exception. An object can contain some state telling the catch clause what to do with the error.

Answer (score 4):

`throw` throws an exception that is caught by a `catch` block and is part of the C++ language.  `SetLastError()` is part of the Windows-specific API by Microsoft that changes the value returned by `GetLastError()`.  In other words, they're completely different!  Throwing an exception unwinds the stack (calls destructors for all local variables) and moves program execution to the appropriate catch block.  `SetLastError()` does nothing like that, it's just an API function.